# Will 6 months on a visitor visa affect an application for a Youth Mobility Scheme Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, australian-citizens

As an Australian currently visiting the UK on a standard 6-month visa-free entrance and staying as a tourist for almost all the allowed 6-month period.

I have decided I would like to stay longer and the YMS visa seems like the best option for that. Would I be able to return to Australia for the period required to apply for a Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa (the process takes 3 weeks to one month, give or take) and directly return to the UK immediately after visa approval?

I'm unsure if a certain period of time would need to be spent outside the UK before returning, even though I would be entering on a different visa.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the [basic rules](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility/eligibility) that prevents you applying.

However, I hope your financial records are in good order because six months is a long time to stay as a tourist with no income. They may think you were working illegally during that time, especially if that six months was spent in one area of the UK, or that you've started a relationship in the UK and are trying to hide it from them.

So you can try, but make sure the bank details you submit show a clear pattern of support which means you wouldn't have to have worked during that six months. e.g. support from family, rent from properties you own in Australia, or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am happy to hear there is nothing that overtly states I cannot re-enter on the different visa immediately. I have an aunt and uncle who live in the UK and I am staying with her which is what is making it so easy for me to stay long term. Would this be reasonable justification to prove I haven't needed to work during my time here? I also have over $5000AU in my bank account, which should be enough for me to support myself when I come back over on the YMS visa until I can find employment. 

Thanks again for your answer!